# Xamarin.Forms Button: Flash Color on Press

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Similar to what's being seen [here in Google's Material Design Responsive Interaction](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B3T7oTWa3HiFOFFrMHpqN3NMQkU/animation_responsiveinteraction_userinput_materialresponse.webm) documentation, I would like to have a button react to being pressed by flashing a color briefly but then returning to the original color gradually.

Can this effect be achieved using the default Xamarin.Forms Button control with a click handler method? Or must a custom renderer be implemented to try and create this effect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the animation methods available on ui components. Essentially you need to add a click handler to your button that runs animations (first your color change, then your gradual fade back using async/await). I have added a link to a sample that animates a size change, but the theory will remain the same.

```
// add a gester reco
this.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
{
    Command = new Command(async (o) =>
    {
        await this.ScaleTo(0.95, 50, Easing.CubicOut);
        await this.ScaleTo(1, 50, Easing.CubicIn);
        if (callback != null)
            callback.Invoke();
    })
});
```